# How can I label vertices of the graph, so they are the same as on the other labeled graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, graph-isomorphism

Is there some algorithm to label equivalent vertices of unlabeled graph?

For example, suppose I have two distinct graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$, and they are isomorophic. However, $G_1$ has labeled vertices and endges, whereas $G_2$ has only edges labeled (edge labels might be different in $G_1$ and $G_2$). Is there any way how I can name vertices in $G_2$, so equivalent vertices to $G_1$ have the same labels?

So if $G_1$ and $G_2$ look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBkFI.png). I need $G_2$ to be like [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2q1H.png).

Comment: Some algorithm certainly exists. You can test all possible ways to label the vertices of $G_2$ and see if the edges of $G_1$ match the edges of $G_2$ and vice versa. I believe you have some complexity constraint for the desired algorithm, though. Which would that be?

Comment: No, there is no such constraint. The faster it works, the better. I was just curious if there is some smart method of doing so, not considering all possible combinations. Nevertheless, thanks for the tip, I will try to implement that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved with *canonical labelings*: compute the canonical labeling of both $G_1$ and $G_2$; if this results in the same (labeled) graph, then $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic. Then vertices with the same label (in the canonical labeling) are equivalent.
But please note that both isomorphisms and canonical labelings are only unique up to automorphism. (e.g.: in your example, vertex 1 and 3 cannot be distinguished.)

The theoretical complexity of the graph isomorphism-problem is still unknown, but in practice there are fast programs such as [nauty](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/nauty/) which will do the job even for large graphs.